# LocalStorage not working when I refresh my page without a network connection

Tags: vue.js, iframe, local-storage, devtools, quasar

So, I'm running a vue application with quasar inside an iframe and while using localStorage, I noticed something strange. When I turn off my connection the application works just fine, because I still have data on localStorage, but when I refresh the page, it returns a browser error and it shows that I can't access that because obviously I'm out of a connection, and it shows that because I lost everything that I had on localStorage.

The thing is I'm still new at this localStorage thing, but I did a lot of research about it and I read about having localStorage even when I close the browser and open it again.

My question is: localStorage should stay after I lost my connection and refresh the page or it works like that? Losing it? and if not, why is this happening? This is more a conceitual question, that's why I didn't post any code, I need to understand the actual behavior that I should see in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure it stays. We have an application with a fully functioning offline mode using localStorage and appCache. You will need to grub down. Open your devTools. What do you see in Application => localStorage? How are you expecting the page resources to be available offline (appCache or serviceWorker)? Are there errors in the console? In the network tab? Theoretically this can work.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering! So, when I turn off my connection the application works just fine, I still have data and i still can see it on Application => localStorage. I want to see the same data after refreshing while offline. There's no errors on console and network tab because he didn't reach any request i think.

Comment: Don't forget about using a service worker for this approach.

Comment: So your problem is that you hit refresh and everything disappears ? That's normal if you have no appCache or service worker. Local storage just looks after your data, not your page. So you need to enable your page to be cached somehow. appCache is deprecated, but still works, and is simpler to get your head around than service workers. Is that your problem?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what is happening, thank you very much I finally understood now how this process should work

Comment: No problem. Don't hesitate to accept the answer if you feel !